# Facility "syslog" in rsyslog.conf effects sd_journal_print() and sd_journal_send()

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, journal

I'm running a Debian Jessie (8.6) machine. I have enabled rsyslogd:

```
rsyslogd 8.4.2, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    memory allocator:           system default
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:               Yes
    Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

I have the following lines in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
*.err;kern,auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,syslog.none    -/var/log/syslog
```

I run a c code that generates logs using:

```
sd_journal_print(LOG_ERR, "Hello World by journal_print");
```

When examining /var/log/syslog file, I do not see the log entry. But journalctl shows the log in journals. If I change the filter in rsyslog.conf to the following, I start seeing the logs in /var/log/syslog:

```
*.err;kern,auth,authpriv,cron,daemon.none    -/var/log/syslog
```

The definition of syslog facility says, "messages generated internally by syslogd".

Can anyone explain why logs generated from user-space via sd_jounral_print() are treated as "internally by syslogd"? Am I doing something wrong or do I have a bad setup?

I would appreciate any help or guidance.